# Common elements in finite LCM closed sets.

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

Let $X$ be a finite set of square-free integers. Suppose that whenever $a, b \in X$, we have $lcm(a, b) \in X$. Does it follow that there exists $x \in X$ that divides at least half of elements of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form in which you pose the question, the answer is negative. A counterexample is afforded by $X=\{2\cdot3\cdot5,3\cdot5\cdot7,5\cdot7\cdot2,7\cdot2\cdot3,2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\}$.

If instead you only demand that some $n\gt1$ divides at least half the elements of $X$, this yields an arithmetic version of the [union-closed sets conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture), which is an open problem.